# Monogame Windows 8 Phone

Tags: monogame, windows-phone-8

I have monogame 3.0.1 (latest stable) installed on a Windows 8 Pro machine. I can create a new Windows Phone 8 project (Monogame template) and deploy to the emulator and an actual device with no problems.

However after successfully getting a screen of cornflour blue I wanted to display a simple image. I know the content pipeline is something that doesnt work but I wanted to display a simple PNG.

For this, I tried:

Adding a Content folder. Adding a simple PNG (test.png) to the content folder. Set the build to "Content" and ensure it was set to "Copy if newer". Then added the following code.

```
texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("test");
```

And in the draw, draw it out. However , I get a NotImplementedException when I try to deploy this.

Out of the box, how do I draw a simple texture/sprite to the screen?

Comment: Where is the NotImplementedException being thrown? Stack trace please.

Answer (score 1):

@Barry MonoGame does not currently generate *.xnb files, but it CAN actually consume them. So if you have an existing *.xnb file add it instead of the png, following the same steps you mentioned in your post and it should work.

Comment: I thought it was also possible to use PNG, JPG files as textures directly rather than XNB compiled files?

Answer (score 0):

When using PNG files or other resources directly you need to specify the file extension when you load it with the content manager. So in your case, try this:

```
texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("test.png");
```

I know this works on Android. I assume it works the same way on other platforms.